# Run function on window resize below specific window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that breaks an address down, line by line based on comma separation. I need to only run this when the window is below 750px and return the text to one line above 750px. I have the following function which breaks the text down:

```
var fixed = $('.location-header > p').text();
var address = fixed.substring(0, fixed.lastIndexOf(',')).replace(/,/g, "<br />") + fixed.substring(fixed.lastIndexOf(','));
$('.location-header > p').html(address);
```

I'm trying to use `.resize()` function in jquery, but it doesn't seem to be triggering properly.

> **When function runs properly, text should look like this:**
>
> 123 Nowhere Ln
>
> Suite 200
>
> Somewhere, NY 10009

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/1vc4fb8r/)**

Comment: Why don't you wrap it in spans and use CSS Media Queries? No JavaScript needed.

Comment: The site is dynamic and can have a multiple line address.

Comment: So it prevents whatever is spitting out the address to wrap it in spans?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but the idea is that there address will be different for different pages. On mobile, the address should wrap as it does when you remove the resize function from the fiddle. When on desktop (above 750px), it should be one line.

Comment: Which is what your question stated. I was asking, what is preventing you from updating the code to wrap the lines of the address in spans. Makes the code cleaner and faster to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With Javascript:** On resize, you can check the window width with $(window).width() and break/unbreak the address accordingly.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mu1zpvoq/

JSFiddle (ES6 + 1 line functions): https://jsfiddle.net/mu1zpvoq/4/

```
var fixed = $('.location-header > p')[0].innerHTML.replace('/(,)(?=\s{1}\D{2}[^\s][^\d{5,}])/g', "<br />");
var address = fixed.substring(0, fixed.lastIndexOf(',')).replace(/,/g, "<br />");

function breakAddress () {
    $('.location-header > p').html(address)
}

function fixAddress () {
    $('.location-header > p').html(fixed)
}

function toggleAddress () {
    if ($(window).width() < 750) {
        breakAddress()
    } else {
        fixAddress()
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', toggleAddress)
$(document).ready(toggleAddress)
```

*HOWEVER* you can definitely just do this **with CSS:**

HTML:

```
<p class="address">
    <span>123 Nowhere Ln</span>
    <span>Suite 200</span>
    <span>Somewhere</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.address > span
    display: block

@media all and (min-width: 750px)
    .address > span
        display: inline

    .address > span:after
        content: ', '
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use CSS media queries ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)) instead of resize callbacks.

You could split the address into separate html elements during the page loaded callback and then change display styles regarding to window's width with media queries.

Comment: The site is dynamic and can have a multiple line address.

Comment: @Matt When CSS is an equivalent solution, it is always better than JavaScript. There is a tradeoff against readability and maintainability. For example, I would favor a JavaScript slideshow over a CSS slideshow.